# How to remove outliers from this box plotting r command

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

I am trying to Boxplot my data frame using this command.

```
ggplot(combined_data,aes(x= factor(field), y=moisture1))+geom_boxplot()
```

How can I remove the outliers from the output of this command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the outliers from your graph, you can just add the argument `outlier.shape = NA` to `geom_boxplot()`

Example:

```
require(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(1, wt)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```